# There is no ViewData element of type « IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create new product but is give me an error on

> dropdown is not type of  IEnumerable

I make some test 
- change method Post to Get for see if data cross url or not and is get data fine

**This is  controller :**

```
  public ActionResult Ajouter()
    {
        db = new IdentityDBEntities2();
        ViewBag.categ = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "libelle");

        return View();
    }



[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Route("Create")]

    public ActionResult Ajouter([Bind(Include = "Ida,description,image,Userid,Idc,titre")] Article article, HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (postedFile != null)
                {
                    db = new IdentityDBEntities2();
                    article.image = Convert.ToString(postedFile.ContentLength);
                    postedFile.InputStream.Read(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(article.image), 0, postedFile.ContentLength);
                    string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
                    string FilePath = "~/Content/img/" + fileName;
                    postedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(FilePath));
                    article.UserId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
                    article.Idc = Convert.ToInt32(Request["Cab"]);
                    article.image = fileName;
                    db.Articles.Add(article);
                    ViewBag.categ = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "libelle");
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");


                }
            }
            else return View(article); 


        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
        return View();
    }
```

**- And this is Dropdown in view :**

```
@Html.DropDownList("categ", null, "-- Select Category -- ", new { id = "subCategory" })
```

**I'm already change dropdown content to**

```
 @Html.DropDownList("categ",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Cab, "-- Select Category -- ", new { id = "subCategory" })
```

But Doesn't work . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign to ViewBag.categ type of `List<Selectlistitem>`, you have to cast Viewbag this type.

```
            //first create List<selectlistitem>
            List<SelectListItem> selectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
            selectListItems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "", Text = "Select" });

            foreach (var item in db.Categories.ToList())
            {
                selectListItems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = item.Id.ToString(), Text = item.Name });
            }

            ViewBag.categ=selectListItems;

           //use it in view
           @Html.DropDownList("categ",(List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.categ, "-- Select Category -- ", new { id = "subCategory" })
```

[image: Result]

//with your code

```
 public ActionResult Ajouter()
        {
            db = new IdentityDBEntities2();
            List<SelectListItem> selectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (var item in db.Categories.ToList())
            {
                selectListItems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = item.Id, Text = item.libelle });
            }
            ViewBag.categ = selectListItems;

            return View();
        }



        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Route("Create")]

        public ActionResult Ajouter([Bind(Include = "Ida,description,image,Userid,Idc,titre")] Article article, HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    if (postedFile != null)
                    {
                        db = new IdentityDBEntities2();
                        article.image = Convert.ToString(postedFile.ContentLength);
                        postedFile.InputStream.Read(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(article.image), 0, postedFile.ContentLength);
                        string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
                        string FilePath = "~/Content/img/" + fileName;
                        postedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(FilePath));
                        article.UserId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
                        article.Idc = Convert.ToInt32(Request["Cab"]);
                        article.image = fileName;
                        db.Articles.Add(article);

                        List<SelectListItem> selectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

                        foreach (var item in db.Categories.ToList())
                        {
                            selectListItems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = item.Id, Text = item.libelle });
                        }
                        ViewBag.categ = selectListItems;
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                }
                else return View(article);


            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
            return View();
        }
```

//dropdown content

```
@Html.DropDownList("categ",(List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.categ, "-- Select Category -- ", new { id = "subCategory" })
```

Comment: Doesn't work brother because second parameter accept IEnumerable VALUE thnaks

Comment: Yes bro brother

Comment: Did you create List<SelectListItem> not SelectList

Comment: Yes brother like you tell me ill show u error on the picture

Comment: Also use db.Categories as db.Categories.ToList()

Comment: where exactly brother

Comment: Add .ToList() extension method to db.Categories

Comment: yes brother i'm update it is is tell me impossible convert select list to select list item on view

Comment: Ok Thanks  brother

Comment: i have written below my answer

Comment: is still the same error of list and listitem im aleady change code you give me but doesn't work

Comment: If you want i could connect you pc to check issue

Comment: Ok brother thanks this is my facebook  https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100016967140017  make teamviewer or give me some link for control machine remotely and resolve this issue

Comment: i have written you from face